Cambiar diseño de popmenu
¿De qué manera es posible cambiar el diseño de los PopMenu? Llevo rato investigando pero no encuentro mucho, pues solo veo cambio de diseño (cómo poner íconos o redondear esquinas) pero yo quisiera cambiar los colores, tanto fondo como letra, ¿es posible y cómo?
Imagen de referencia:

Por el momento solo cuento con un xml básico por así decirlo, tanto el del menú como donde se implementa ese menú, aquí se los muestro:
Código del menu
<?xml versión="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:title="@string/action_about" />
</menú>

Código donde se implementa
(lo implementé en base a un ícono como tal, no puse una barra total por eso el código es corto, más adelante muestro lo demás)
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/menuButton"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu_button_description"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Archivo kt
val menuButton: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.menuButton)
        menuButton.setOnClickListener {
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, menuButton)
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_home)

            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.action_settings -> {
                        val intent = Intent(this, ConfiguracionActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.action_about -> {
                        val intent = Intent(this, AcercadeActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }

            popupMenu.show()
        }

Deseo cambiar tanto el color del fondo como de la letra, eso es lo único que no he encontrado; he visto que redondean los bordes y cambian donde aparece, pero eso no es lo que busco.

Bienvenido. Carga el XML

Estás en [es.so]. Traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Elimina toda la parte que está en inglés. Debes publicar tu pregunta sólo en español.

Tal como te han dicho: muestra el XML, y además modifica tu pregunta para que solo esté en español.
